# How do I calculate $2^{47} \pmod{\! 65}$?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I'm trying to calculate $2^{47}\pmod{\! 65}$, but I don't know how...

I know that: $65=5\cdot 13$ and that:

$2^{47}\equiv 3 \pmod{\! 5}$ and $2^{47}\equiv 7\pmod{\! 13}$... (I used Euler)

But how should I continue from here? (I saw at WolframAlpha that the result is 33, but I don't have any idea how to get it...)

I'd like to get any help...

Thank you!

Comment: What is $2^6$? How does that help?

Comment: @Yoar, just to use fermat little theorem

Comment: Hint: $65=64+1$

Comment: @whacka - but 65 is not prime...

Comment: @salimmath15 - Fermat is only for primes, right?

Comment: but you can write it as sum of  primes number such that :65=47+7+11

Comment: Elaboration on my hint: $64\equiv-1$ mod $65$. Primality is irrelevant. Sun-Ze (aka the Chinese Remainder Theorem) is a bit overpowered for this problem, and provides no tradeoff in terms of efficiency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\varphi(65)=(5-1)(13-1)=48$, so by [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Euler%27s_theorem) (since $(2,65)=1$):

$$2x\equiv 2\cdot 2^{47}\equiv 2^{48}\equiv 1\pmod{\! 65}$$

$$2x\equiv 66\stackrel{:2}\iff x\equiv 33\pmod{\! 65}$$

Answer (score 4):

$2^6=64$, so $\,2^6\equiv -1 \pmod{\! 65}\,$ and $47=6\cdot 7+5$; then $2^{47}\equiv (2^6)^7\cdot 2^5\equiv (-1)^7\cdot 32\equiv  -32 \equiv 33 \pmod{\! 65}$

Answer (score 2):

You might find these two facts helpful.  $$2^6 =64\equiv -1\ \ \pmod{65}  $$
and
$$(2^a)^b=2^{ab}$$

Answer (score 1):

As $65=5\cdot13$  with $(5,13)=1,$

$2^6=64\equiv-1\pmod{13}$ and $2^6\equiv-1\pmod5$

$\implies2^6=64\equiv-1\pmod{13\cdot5}$

Now $47\equiv-1\pmod6\implies2^{47}\equiv2^{-1}\pmod{65}$

As $33\cdot2-65=1,2\cdot33\equiv1\pmod{65}\iff2^{-1}\equiv33$